# Mysql SELECT statement order by count

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure if this is possible or not

I have a table with `orders` and `userid`

I need to do a `SELECT` query with `ORDER BY` the least number of orders of a customer

Example:

```
userid1 has 10 orders
userid2 has 5 orders
```

Then `SELECT` should show `userid2` at the top

Thanks in advance

Comment: show you query please

Comment: Like this.. ? `SELECT user FROM table ORDER BY orders ASC`

Comment: anyway, `ORDER BY count(whatever);`

Comment: Do you want all orders records in ordered by user.ordercount? Or just users in the order?

Comment: There is no user.ordercount, this is a thing that should be calculated in the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have orders as ordersCount i mean as a field which keeps counts of orders then

```
Select * FROM YourTable order by orders ASC
```

Else if you have a record for each order then

```
Select * FROM YourTable Group by UserID order by count(*) ASC;
```

Apply limit like this

```
Select * 
     FROM YourTable 
     Group by UserID 
     order by count(*) ASC 
     limit startIndex, fetchSize;
```

where startIndex and fetchSize are int that define your limit

Comment: @SeifHatem do mention which one of the query helped you? first or second

Comment: The second one as I don't have a table having each user order count 

I just have a table for all orders

Comment: Is there a way to set LIMIT in the second query?

Comment: Can you help with it please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by the `userid` so you can count orders by user.

`SELECT userid, count(1) FROM orders GROUP BY userid ORDER BY count(1) asc`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using GROUP BY and ordering by COUNT().

It would be something like that.

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) qt
FROM orders
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY qt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `COUNT` of a column and give it a name, then use that name to sort by. Here's an example:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(o.order_id) FROM orders AS o WHERE p.partron_id=p.patron_id) AS orderCount
FROM
    patrons AS p
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY
    orderCount ASC
```

**UPDATE:** Just realized this is only useful if you have orders in a separate table than patrons. Disregard if you are only looking at a single table.

This query expects you to have two tables, a `patron` table with patron information like name, and a `orders` table that has a `patron_id` column that matches the identity column in the `patron` table.

The advantage to doing this is that you can request patron information at the same time, so you don't need to run two queries in PHP if you're going to use that information.

Answer (score 0):

If each order is in its own row, however, you need to aggregate them:

```
SELECT * from MYTABLENAME GROUP BY userid ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is what you're looking for

```
SELECT count(theField) as theCount, *
FROM theTable
GROUP BY theField
ORDER BY theCount
```